# Does each Instance in SQL Server have to have a specific instance based port number?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012. I found that, MSSQLSERVER is a default instance which has 1433 as a default port number.

Now, I create a new instance named "INSTANCE1". "**Do I have to specify separate port number for this instance or INSTANCE1 uses 1433 port by default?**"

Is port number Instance specific or it have some other explanation for ports usability?

Answer (score 0):

> Does each Instance in SQL Server have to have a specific instance based port number ?

Answer is yes,think of like SQL SERVER as a process ,like all normal processes ,this needs unique port number when it is running

When you assign Default of 1433 to both the instances,only one can run at a time.